# Framer motion animates smoothly based on tailwind classes, but not when specifying values using animate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, framer-motion

I got framer motion to animate smoothly based on className, but when I take the values of those class names and set them explicitly in Animate, they no longer animate smoothly.

As you can see, I took the values that the tailwind classnames were providing, and tried to add them to a Variants object.  Whereas swapping the classnames resulted in smooth transitions, setting them via props jumps around.

works:

```tsx
const containerStyle = ` ${isMaximized ? 'fixed inset-0' : ' aspect-[16/9]'}`;
  const motionDivStyle = isMaximized ? 'h-screen w-screen' : 'h-full';

  return (
    <div className="aspect-[16/9]">
      <AnimatePresence>
        <div className={containerStyle} onClick={() => {
          setIsMaximized(!isMaximized)
        }}>
          <motion.div
            whileHover={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}
            layout
            transition={trans}
            className={`${message[i]} ${motionDivStyle}`}
          >
            <motion.div layout="position">hello</motion.div>
          </motion.div>
        </div>
      </AnimatePresence>
    </div>
  );
};
```

does not work:

```
  const variants: Variants = {
    maximized: {
      position: 'fixed',
      inset: '0px',
      aspectRatio: 'auto' 
    },
    minimized: {
      position: 'static',
      inset: 'auto', 
      aspectRatio: '16/9' 
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="aspect-[16/9]">

      <motion.div onClick={() => {
        setIsMaximized(!isMaximized)
      }}

        transition={trans}
        initial={'minimized'}
        variants={variants}
        animate={isMaximized ? 'maximized' : 'minimized'
        }
      >
```